# Reusable component to avoid multiple codes

Tags: reactjs

Since I am pretty new to react, I am calling the component multiple times in my code due to some conditions.

Can you please share the best method to avoid repeated codes.

```
{!account && !wButton && (
  <Menu
    color="black"
    size="medium"
    onClick={() => mobileMenu()}
  />
)}



{account && isMenuActive && !wButton && (
  
  <Menu
    color="black"
    size="medium"
    onClick={() => mobileMenu()}
  />
)}


{account && isMenuActive && !wButton && logedin&&(
  
  <Menu
    color="black"
    size="medium"
    onClick={() => mobileMenu()}
  />
)}
```

Comment: From your code, I can see your primary condition is `isMenuActive && !wButton`. You only need to render `Menu` whenever that condition matched, so you can group all of them together like `{isMenuActive && !wButton && <Menu .../>}`

Comment: Above code i have added is a part. Still I have 8 more  if conditions rendering the same component. Is there any other way like render the <Menu > component like Json or objects etc. May be i am wrong also.

Comment: you can try to add `const ConditionalMenu = () => <Menu .../>` and call it like `<ConditionalMenu />` but it just helps to reduce lines of code

Comment: Let me try . Thank you

Comment: Is it all result the same component with same props?

Comment: yes same props only the position change